# Movies Anywhere ID?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to automate requesting movies from different retailers on Movies Anywhere. The URL for the request is: `https://retailer.moviesanywhere.com/api/purchase/initiate?retailer={retailer}&id={id}&redirectURI=https%3A%2F%2Fmoviesanywhere.com%2Fmovie%2F{slug}`

If you replace `{retailer}` with `VUD`, `{id}` with `10.5240/870D-6EC1-415D-4FDC-B5DC-T`, and `{slug}` with `the-incredibles` you'll be be redirected to The Incredibles on Vudu.

Here is a list of all retailers and their ids for The Incredibles:

- `VUD = 10.5240/870D-6EC1-415D-4FDC-B5DC-T`
- `GOO = 105240870D6EC1415D4FDCB5DCT`
- `APL = 88702939`
- `AMZ = 10.5240/870D-6EC1-415D-4FDC-B5DC-T`
- `FAN = 10.5240/870D-6EC1-415D-4FDC-B5DC-T`

The problem is, I can't figure out how to find when these are gotten by Movies Anywhere. I tried setting a breakpoint on the click event and stepping through the JavaScript but I'm not getting anywhere. Does anyone know how to get this ID when clicking the Buy button for each retailer?